# Send Email with C++ WINSOCK (TCP, SSL)

Tags: c++, email, ssl, smtp, winsock2

I've been trying for days to send a short, plain-text email to myself with C++. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015. I'm eventually hoping to email automatic alerts to myself. I am using a Gmail account. I can't seem to manage to get this to work. I can send data, but can't receive. The server is closing my connection with Error 10054. (You can read about what that error means on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Here is the history: I have cobbled all this together from lots of S.O. posts and MSDN articles. I used to have a functional [WSASetSocketSecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394823(v=vs.85).aspx) section in this code, but for whatever reason, my connection attempts were timing out, so I omitted it. At this point, I will settle for the server not severing my connection when I send EHLO or HELO.

I'm really at a loss for how to proceed. Days of exploration, dozens of read articles, hundreds of dead ends. I hope that you'll forgive the few bits of junk code and that S.O. removed my hand alignments. Please take a look, let me know what I am doing wrong, let me know of any improper style, or anything else that offends your good-coder sensibilities. Many thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // In-out stream objects for development
#include <stdio.h> // Standard in-out for development

#include <winsock2.h> // For making socket connection to email server
#include <Mstcpip.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h> // Enhanced protocols to assist winsock2.h

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") // Library for winsock2.h
#pragma comment(lib, "Fwpuclnt.lib") // Library for winsock2.h

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

using namespace std;
void cleanup(SOCKET ConnectSocket, struct addrinfo *result) {
    if (ConnectSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    cout << "socket closed" << endl;
    cin.get(); // Development only
}

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize email parameters
    char            bccAddresses[64] = "";
    char            fromAddress[64] = "my_email@host.com";
    char            msg[512] = "Hello world!";
    char            port[12] = "465";
    char            serverName[64] = "smtp.host.com";
    char            toAddresses[64] = "my_email@host.com";
    SOCKET          ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *ptr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    WSADATA         wsaData;

    try {
        // Initialize Winsock
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << iResult << endl;
            throw std::exception("WSAStartup failed\n");
        }
        cout << "WSAStartup successful: " << iResult << endl;

        // Set up the hints socket address structure
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_flags = AI_SECURE;
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo(serverName, port, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("getaddrinfo failed\n");
        }
        cout << "getaddrinfo successful: " << iResult << endl;

        // Connect to the socket
        ptr = result;
        ConnectSocket = WSASocket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("Error at socket\n");
        }
        cout << "WSASocket successful: " << iResult << endl;

        // Connect via the socket
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            throw std::exception("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        }
        cout << "connect successful: " << iResult << endl;

        // Send message
        char sendBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "What is your malfunction";
        char recvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        sprintf_s(sendBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "EHLO %s%s", serverName, "\r\n");
        iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("WINSOCK send failed\n");
        }
        cout << "Sent:\n" << sendBuffer << "Byte count: " << iResult << endl;

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("WINSOCK recv failed\n");
        }
        cout << "EHLO response: " << iResult << endl;
        sprintf_s(sendBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "QUIT%s", "\r\n");
        iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("WINSOCK send failed\n");
        }
        cout << "Sent:\n" << sendBuffer << "Byte count: " << iResult << endl;
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        if (iResult < 0) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("WINSOCK recv failed\n");
        }
        cout << "Quit response: " << iResult << endl;

        // Shutdown the connection
        iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            throw std::exception("shutdown failed\n");
        }
        // Clean up
        cleanup(ConnectSocket, result);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (std::exception err) {
        printf(err.what());
        cleanup(ConnectSocket, result);
        return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        printf("Unknown error\n");
        cleanup(ConnectSocket, result);
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: I will later be separating my login information from the hard code. It's in there now for simplicity while I am developing.

Comment: Oh, I am dumb... I'll post my solution soon, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Three parts to this answer.

1. MIME Encode the username and password.
2. ACTUALLY send the username and password! :)
3. Some servers are skeptical and want you to say HELO or EHLO twice.

I will post full code soon. Although I feel I was about 40% of the way there, I owe my success to this site: http://www.coastrd.com/smtps.